# How to rectify "Use flow" keyframe when its not working?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I wanted to stop the fluid flow after certain key-frame but even though i inserted a key frame in "Use flow" check box by checking and unchecking it , the flow keeps on producing .Help me to stop the flow after certain key-frame

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit hard to understand. How many keyframes did you insert? You inserted "a keyframe" (= 1 keyframe?) "by checking and unchecking it"? So did you set the keyframe while _Use Flow_ was checked or unchecked? And if both, on the same frame or different frames?

Comment: you have to have 2 keyframes: 1 unchecked, and one frame later checked

Comment: I had different keyframes For example Till  Keyframe 10 is checked and keyfrme 11 is unchecked . But still water keeps on flowing